# Does HaProxy Supports "API Gateway" Feature like NGINX

Tags: authentication, haproxy, api-gateway

We are evaluating reverse proxies which support API Gateway feature. We tested the API Gateway feature in NGINX with a custom authentication Application. The request flow in NGINX is that when a request reaches NGINX, it forwards the request for authentication to a custom authentication application. If the auth application returns HTTP 200, NGINX forwards the request to downstream servers.

HaProxy: 
       For HAP proxy I am unable to figure out how to integrate the custom authentication application in HAProxy configurations.

Kindly guide me to the correct configuration/resource for me to proceed.

Comment: If we consider an "API Gateway" as a reverse proxy doing load-balancing, header/URL based routing, monitoring, traffic shaping.  
Then HAProxy supports "API Gateway" feature. Can you provide more details or a concrete example about custom authentication application?

Comment: I am looking for a functionality similar to nginx where, each incoming http request is first checked for Auth then only nginx forwards the request to downstream application. I am looking for this Auth functionality

Comment: I am looking for the following functionality in HAProxy.  https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/restricting-access-auth-request/